# US International keyboard layout dead keys behaving inconsistently

Tags: keyboard, windows-8.1, keyboard-layout, dead-keys

I use the US International keyboard layout, which makes it easy to produce a whole bunch of special characters without alt codes or third-party software. It usually works fine, but sometimes the dead keys don't work the way they're supposed to.

Expected behavior when following a dead key with...

Compatible character → special character (`'a` → `á`)
Incompatible character → literal value for both keys (`'t` → `'t`)
A dead key again → literal value for both keys (`~~` → `~~`)
Space → literal value of dead key (`"`  → `"`)

However, in some applications (usually resource-intensive ones like games, e.g. Star Trek Online, League of Legends, Rift), it doesn't work. I may instead get a doubled dead key value followed by whatever character I typed next, like `'a` → `''a` and `"`  → `""` . And I really do mean "may" - sometimes it consistently works correctly, sometimes it always does the wrong behavior, and sometimes I can hammer e.g. `'o'o'o'o'o'o'o'o'o'o'o'o'o'o'o'o` and end up with something like `''o''o''o''oóó''oó''oóó''oóóó''o`.

What is causing this, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: You tagged Windows 8.1, is this correct? If so try a newer one like Windows 10, for starters. Win8.x is about to become EoL if not already.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - Do you have a source explaining what causes this, why it's specific to 8.1, and how 10 resolves it?